# how to add a string to the path in link_to of ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example I have this code:

```
<%= link_to "Start", start_path(:id=>1,:box=>1)%>
```

the `id` and the `box` are parameters right?
and for example, it generated this url: http://localhost:3000/start?id=1&box=1

How can I add a string to it, to make look like this:

http://localhost:3000/start?id=1&box=1#box_1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:anchor` key:

```
<%= link_to "Start", start_path(:id => 1, :box => 1, :anchor => 'box_1')
```

And to answer your first question, yes, `id` and `box` are parameters. They are passed in to the request as part of the `params` hash.